# Updating component data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've the following component structure.

```
<Dashboard>
   <UserData />
   <MealList />
   <Search />
</Dashboard>
```

I'm fetching the contents for `UserData` and `MealList` using `useEffects` inside dashboard and passing them down as props.

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [calories, setCalories] = useState("");
    const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);

 useEffect(async () =>{
        const data = await fetchUserData(localStorage.getItem('email'));
        localStorage.setItem('user_id', data['id']);
        setUsername(data['username']);
        setEmail(data['email']);
        setCalories(data['calories']);
        const mealsData = await fetchMeals(localStorage.getItem('user_id'));
        setMeals([...meals, ...mealsData]);

    }, []);
```

Now what I want to implement is based on search parameters the meal list refreshes.

I'm grabbing the search parameters from the Search component and passing it back to the `MealList`.

Then I make a REST call and fetch the updated data.

```
const updateList = async ( ft, tt, fd, td) =>{
        const userId = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
        const updatedMealsList = await searchMeals(userId, ft, tt, fd, td);
        console.log('Updated Meals', updatedMealsList);
        setMeals([]);//Tried this but doesn't work
        setMeals([...meals, ...updatedMealsList]);//
    };
```

My question is how do I update the Meallist array and re-render the component?

I've already tried this, and it doesn't work. What I mean by doesn't work is neither is data in the `meals` array updated nor is it being re-rendered.

Here are the components.

```
const Dashboard = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [calories, setCalories] = useState("");
    const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);

    useEffect(async () =>{
        const data = await fetchUserData(localStorage.getItem('email'));
        localStorage.setItem('user_id', data['id']);
        setUsername(data['username']);
        setEmail(data['email']);
        setCalories(data['calories']);
        const mealsData = await fetchMeals(localStorage.getItem('user_id'));
        setMeals([...meals, ...mealsData]);

    }, []);


    const updateList = async ( ft, tt, fd, td) =>{
        const userId = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
        const updatedMealsList = await searchMeals(userId, ft, tt, fd, td);
        setMeals([]);
        console.log('Updated Meals', updatedMealsList);
        setMeals([...meals, ...updatedMealsList]);
    };
    console.log('Updated Meals', meals);
    return (
        <div>
            <Navigation/>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div style={{display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'row wrap'}}>
                    <UserData username={username} email={email} calories={calories}/>
                    <Search onSubmit={updateList}/>
                </div>
                <MealList meals={meals}/>

            </div>

        </div>

    )
};
export default Dashboard;
```

Meallist

```
const MealList = (props) => {
    return (
        <div style={{width: '70%'}}>
            <h3 style={{color: 'grey', fontSize: '1.4em', fontWeight: '700', marginBottom: '1em'}}><FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faPlusCircle} style={{color: '#007bff', marginRight: '0.5em'}}/> ADD MEAL</h3>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Meal</th>
                    <th>Calories</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {props.meals.map((meal, index) => (<Meal count={index +1} meal={meal}/>))}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>

    )
};
export default MealList;
```

Comment: On the first example, where did you get the `meals` array because I have seen only `mealsData`? Also try to use React dev tools to inspect the aforementioned arrays/data.

Comment: Are you passing the `setMeals` function down as a prop from `Dashboard` to the `Meallist` component? From reading the question I'm assuming the `updateList` call is coming from there... once you pass the function down to the correct component it should work just fine.

Comment: @Edper I've updated the questions with the useState which brings the meals in context.

Comment: @Ryan No, I'm using the setMeals to update the meals array in the Dashboard and then passing the updated state down.

Comment: Giving `useEffect` an async function should be giving a warning.

Comment: We'd probably need to see more code to understand how you are passing data back and forth between components. Most likely the issue is in that behavior

Comment: If there is no passing down of props how can it re-render then the `MealsList` component? Unless all the code you are showing here are under `MealsList` component? Also, could you show the `MealsList` and `Dashboard` components and also the `setMeals` method, at least what is necessary in the code for discussion.

Comment: you said I'm fetching the contents for UserData and MealList using useEffects inside dashboard and passing them down as props.

does it mean that an array is passed as a prop to MealList Component ?

if yes, then for your implementation to work, the array of meals needs to be tracked in a state variable at dashboard level.

overall, I think you should have mentioned this info as part fo your question.

Comment: @Edper updated my question.

Comment: @Ryan updated my question.

Comment: @AppleCiderGuy updated the question.

Comment: @BrandonDyer it is giving one, which I'll fix later.

Comment: Check your `setMeals()` function that you use in your hook if it does what it should. It would be good that you use the React Developer Tools so that you don't have to use `console.log()` and inspect the values from there. Also, you did not show your `setMeals()` function. By the way I assume that your `<Meal>` uses `<tr>` and `<td>` since you have only `<tbody>` in your `MealsList`.

Answer (score 1):

First, I advise you to read the following article

https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

this explains in detail how to properly use the useEffect hook

```js
let dynamicMealId = 3;
function delay(payload) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(payload)
    }, 350)
  })
}

function fetchUserData(email) {
  return delay({
    id: Date.now(),
    username: 'johndoe@doe.com',
    calories: 2000
  })
}

function fetchMeals(userId) {
  return delay([{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Meal 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Meal 2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Meal 3'
  }])
}

function searchMeals(userId, filters) {
  return delay(Array.from({length: 3}, (v, k) => k+1).map(function () {
    const meal = {
      id: dynamicMealId,
      name: 'Meal ' +  dynamicMealId
    }
    dynamicMealId++;
    return meal;
  }))
}

function UserData(props) {
   return (
     <div>
       {props.user ? (
          <React.Fragment>
            <h1>UserData</h1>
            <div>{props.user.username}</div>
            <div>{props.user.calories}</div>
          </React.Fragment>
        ) : (
          <span>Loading User...</span>
        )}
     </div>
   );
}

function Search(props) {
  
  function handleSubmit(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    props.onSearch(ev.target.elements[0].value);
    
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h1>Search</h1>
      <label forHtml="input">
        Enter Keyword
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="input"/>
    </form>
  )
}

function MealList(props) {
  console.log(props.meals)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>MealList</h1>
      <ul>
        {props.meals.map(function(meal) {
         return (
           <li key={meal.id}>{meal.name}</li>
         )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}


const Dashboard = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null)
  const [meals, setMeals] = React.useState(null)
  const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState(null)
  
  // loads user data
  React.useEffect(() => {
     function loadData() {
       fetchUserData('some@email.com')
         .then((userData) => {
           setUser(userData);
           return fetchMeals(userData.id)
         })
         .then((userMeals) => {
           setMeals(userMeals);
         });
    }
    
    loadData();
  }, []);
  
  // loads new meals
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!user || !filters) { return; }
    
    function search() {
      searchMeals(user.id, filters)
        .then(newMeals => {
          setMeals(currentMeals => [
            ...currentMeals,
            ...newMeals
          ])
        })
    }
    
    search();
  }, [user, filters]);
  

  
  return (
    <div>
      Dashboard
      <UserData user={user}/>
      {user && meals && (
        <div>
          <Search onSearch={newFilters => setFilters(newFilters)} />
          <MealList 
            meals={meals}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <Dashboard />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Search is a sibling of MealList, so the communication between the two can only happen inside the Dashboard. You might wanna read the question again.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, can you please take a look at my repo, https://github.com/melissa-stewart/mealplan